# Incompatible shapes error while training ConvNet using Keras+Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a simple convolutional neural network to classify time series into one-of-six classes. I am having an issue with training the network due to incompatible shapes error.

In the following code, `n_feats = 1000`, `n_classes = 6`.

```
Fs = 100
input_layer = Input(shape=(None, n_feats), name='input_layer')
conv_layer = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=Fs*4, strides=int(Fs/2), padding='same', activation='relu', name='conv_net_coarse')(input_layer)
conv_layer = MaxPool1D(pool_size=4, name='c_maxp_1')(conv_layer)
conv_layer = Dropout(rate=0.5, name='c_dropo_1')(conv_layer)
output_layer = Dense(n_classes, name='output_layer')(conv_layer)

model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

Here is the model summary.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_layer (InputLayer)     (None, None, 1000)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_net_coarse (Conv1D)     (None, None, 32)          12800032  
_________________________________________________________________
c_maxp_1 (MaxPooling1D)      (None, None, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
c_dropo_1 (Dropout)          (None, None, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
output_layer (Dense)         (None, None, 6)           198       
=================================================================
Total params: 12,800,230
Trainable params: 12,800,230
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

When I run, `model.fit(X_train, Y_train)`, where `X_train` shape is `(30000, 1, 1000)` and `Y_train` shape is `(30000, 1, 6)`, I get incompatible shapes error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [32,0,6] vs. [1,6,1]
     [[Node: output_layer/add = Add[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](output_layer/Reshape_2, output_layer/Reshape_3)]]
     [[Node: metrics_1/acc/Mean/_197 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_637_metrics_1/acc/Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

If I remove the `MaxPool1D` and `Dropout` layers, the model trains just fine. Am I not specifying those layers correctly?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a single time series or multiple ones? Because now you have `30000` sequences of length `1` with `1000` features. Am I right?

Comment: I have 30000 samples with 1000 features. So basically I have a matrix of shape `30000 X 1000`. If I use this 2D matrix as input, Keras gives me error saying that 3 dimensions are expected. Hence I reshaped it into `30000 X 1 X 1000`. Same with the output.

Comment: Do you want to cut a sequence into chunks or feed the whole sequence at once?

Comment: I want to classify the whole sequence of length 1000. I don't want to cut it further into chunks.

Comment: Ok - so `1000` is a length of a sequence, right?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: So changing to shape `30000 x 1000 x 1` should do the job.

Comment: That gives me error: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_layer to have shape (None, None, 1000) but got array with shape (30000, 1000, 1)`. Do I need to change the shape of the `input_layer`?

Comment: Change input shape to `(1000, 1)`

Comment: Ok. But then something gets messed up with the `output_layer`. I get this error: `ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 5 and 6 for 'output_layer_6/add' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [?,5,6], [1,6,1].`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164128/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-kedarps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So - the problem lies in two facts:

1. The input shape should be `(number_of_examples, timesteps, features)` where the feature is something recorded per time step. This means that you should reshape your data to `(number_of_examples, 1000, 1)` as your time sequence has 1000 timesteps and 1 feature.
2. As you are solving classification task - you need to squash your input to vector (from a sequence). I'd advice you to use `Flatten` before `Dropout` layer.